# Guake Fails to Start

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, guake

Hello I have been using guake terminal for a while on ubuntu 14.04 and older version.

After I have freshly installed (not upgraded) 16.04 xenial and installed guake it didn't work. I start the program the icon appears in the unity bar blinks a bit and disappears.

Maybe some one have also had his problem and fixed it and can help me? 
Or can some one knows where should I try to look for the logs of the initialization of the program so I could have a clue where the problem occurs?

Thank you in advance !:) PS I tried to google it and tried to search in this forum but many post are about the auto start when the OS boots up.

Comment: The procedure to debug problems like this is to start another terminal and enter "guake", then look for any error messages. BTW the default way to open guake is to press F12, does that work?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but I do not see any [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/bugtrackers/guake).

Comment: I have tried to run it from terminal using command  $ guake  ;  But I get this back:  /usr/local/bin/python2: No module named guake  ;

Comment: Try to reinstall the package.

Comment: I did that multiple times,  with rebooting the system.  Also tried to use different repos like webupd8team,  but it doesn't help.  It would be easier for me if would get any error code or something,  but unfortunately I won't get them...

Comment: Do you have a file `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py ` (and several others in that folder)? If so, execute `python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py` in a terminal.

Comment: @Jos executing ```python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py``` returns

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/main.py", line 27, in
 <module>
    import dbus
ImportError: No module named dbus```